# How to clear childViewHolder focus when parentView collapse?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, focus, expandablerecyclerview

I don't know how to remove edit text focus after I clicked / type on the edit text. The application stopped running when I clicked on the collapse button. This is the error it gives out:-

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main  Process: my.mimos.fssm.fosimapp, PID: 3915
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of
>   this view at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:4882)

I'm working on expandable recycler view by **bignerdranch**. My parent list view has a **textview** (the name of the list) and a collapse **button** (where it act as google for the child view). As for my child view, I added a **editText**, where use is enable to leave a comment regarding the textview.

**ExpandableAdapter.java**

```
import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Adapter.ExpandableRecyclerAdapter;
import com.bignerdranch.expandablerecyclerview.Model.ParentListItem;

public class ATPExpandableAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<ATPParentViewHolder, ATPChildViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    Context mContext;
    ArrayList<ATPParent> mParentItemList;
    public static final String TAG = ATPExpandableAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    public ATPExpandableAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ATPParent> parentItemList) {
        super(parentItemList);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mContext = context;
        mParentItemList = parentItemList;
    }

    @Override
    public ATPParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_atp_parent, viewGroup, false);
        return new ATPParentViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public ATPChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_atp_child, viewGroup, false);
        return new ATPChildViewHolder(view);
    }

//    todo: continued here
    @Override
    public void onBindParentViewHolder(final ATPParentViewHolder atpParentViewHolder, final int i, ParentListItem parentObject) {
        ATPParent atpParent = (ATPParent) parentObject;
        atpParentViewHolder.mATP_textview.setText(atpParent.getTitle());

        //when user clicked on parent view
        atpParentViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: parentView");
            }
        });

        atpParentViewHolder.mParentDropDownArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: expandable button");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(final ATPChildViewHolder atpChildViewHolder, int i, Object childObject) {
        final ATPChild atpChild = (ATPChild) childObject;


        String text = atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.getText().toString();
        if(!text.equals("")) {
            atpChild.setDetail(text);
            atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.setText(atpChild.getDetail());
        } else {
            atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.setText(atpChild.getDetail());
        }

        atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    atpChild.setDetail(atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.getText().toString());
                    atpChildViewHolder.mCatatanInput.setText(atpChild.getDetail());
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I tried a lot of thing but not of it seemed to work for me.
This is my expandable recycler view.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIlf9.png)

Comment: i don't know how to call editText focus from chilhdviewholder inside ParentViewHolder... any ideas? The focus should be gone after user comment or collapse the parent view.

Comment: the error happened because the editText still has focus when, user clicked on collapse button. (missing view)

Comment: `public ATPParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
        mView = itemView;
        mATP_textview = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.input_atp);
        mParentDropDownArrow = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_list_item_expand_arrow);
        mParentDropDownArrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (isExpanded()) { collapseView(); }
               else { expandView(); }
            }
        });`

Answer (score 1):

## Expandable RecyclerView

you can use this library.
It is very Useful Custom RecyclerViewAdapters for expanding and collapsing groups with support for multiple view types.

> ExpandableRecyclerView:

```
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.3'
```

> ExpandableCheckRecyclerView:

```
implementation 'com.thoughtbot:expandablecheckrecyclerview:1.4'
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/expandable-recycler-view

[Custom Expand / Collapse Animations example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNEJP.gif)

Comment: Is it impossible to remove the edit text focus? but thank you for suggesting the library.

Comment: YES*

**Remove focus but remain focusable**


editText.setFocusable(false);

Comment: that's the problem. i don't know how to call or pass it from **parentViewHolder**